# how can i calculate the mutual information

Tags: probability, information-theory, mutual-information

I have a vector of continuous random variables X and Y. Y has the value of 0 or 1. I want to calculate which random variable from vector X has more information that makes Y to be 1 using mutual information.How can I do that?

Comment: If Y is continuous how can it only have values 0 or 1?

Comment: Sorry, Y is discrete.

Comment: @mdewey can you give a hint how can I do that when y is discrete?